# Link profile with login

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm developing a competition platform for my sport and I'm kind of stuck with a problem I'm not sure whether to identify it as a database design problem or a programming problem. I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Example: I'm the organizer of a competition. I need to register all the athletes for this competition and I do so by searching the athlete database to see if he is already exists. If the athlete isn't found, I just create a new one on the fly.
Later, the athlete comes and wants to register to the page, he wants to create a login. I want to link his login to his athlete profile and I thought I'd do so by having a login table and an athlete table and somehow link those two. I'm sure how to go about that exactly, though. How can I check which athlete profile belongs to the person that's creating a login. How do I create the link between those two tables. I know that it's done with a foreign key, that's not my issue. But how do I go about "Hey you want to create your own login? Look, I think I found your already existing athlete profile, should I link your login to it?"

Do you understand, what my question is? If more information is needed, let me know. I'm struggling to explain myself.

Comment: Do you have the athlete's email? What information about the athlete do you have at the moment that  you are registering them? If you have only their names, I think you will need to match it with the given name by the user on registration. If there is more than one record with that name, you can show some info to the user, so he can choose his record

Comment: Well the full name is always given. E-Mail maybe... Most competition registrations today are done via paper forms, where they can choose whether or not to provide an email address. I will also implement an online registration form where the athlete has to provide an email address and can register for the website later on if he hasn't done so already. So the thing is probably, that I can never be sure 100%, right? I thought about doing the link via email addresses, but isn't it bad practice to store the email address twice? once in the athletes profile and once for the login?

Comment: You don't need to store the email twice, you can do this with one single table. Will you accept users that was not previously registered by you? If you won't, you can make them fill the form and search for the matching record, if is there any. Then, you use the given information to update the record. If you have their email, it will be much better, since you can confirm it by sending an email with confirmation link.

Comment: If you will accept it, you can do the same, just make sure to create a new record if a matching record was not found.

Comment: If you need two separate tables for email info and profile info, you may do like this: When a new user is registered by you, create a "plain" record with the email (if you have it) on the login table, then link it to its the profile record.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I will think of a few things!

Comment: I tried to make thins more clear on the answer, please check it. Hope this heps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two tables, one for profile info and another one to store login info. When you save a new athlete, make sure you create both records (login and profile) even if you don't have any information about the user's login. Since you will already have a login record, you can link the profile record to it. When the user come to your system to register himself, just fetch the records with the given info (like email, name, etc) and update it.

The email can be stored only on login table.

You can use e-mail confirmation to make things more secure.

Comment: Thanks, your answer brought me to the right path :)